# Efficiently updating Active Directory attribute with large amount of records

Tags: c#, active-directory, console-application

I need some advice on what would be an efficient way to process around 15K of records in Active Directory. In my `List<string> employeeCN` variable I stored around 15K of `employee id` to process in Active Directory. The goal is to update one attribute `a-excludelock` in active directory every employee id in my list.

Currently, I have the below piece of code. I ran it as my baseline and it took around 35 minutes to finished and update all the employee id in my array.

```
using (DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("my_ldap", "my_username", "my_password"))
{
    DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
    
    // employeeCN is a list of string with 15K+ of data
    foreach (string empId in employeeCN)
    {
        try
        {
            string filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(&(cn={empId})))";
            directorySearcher.Filter = filter;
            var searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();

            if (searchResult != null)
            {
                var de = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                de.Properties["a-excludelock"].Value = "Y";
                de.CommitChanges();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: Log an error here why there's an error on the said employee id
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

If I used `Parallel.Foreach` does this give me some performance benefits?

TIA!

Comment: Why do you use search for every single item within loop? You can use `FindAll` for multiple entries and use asynchronous mode

Comment: hey @PavelAnikhouski can you share some code snippet on how to do it? Not sure on how do I implement what you've suggested.

Comment: I don't have AD to implement something, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) tell you more

Comment: I'm not really sure if you understand correctly what I'm trying to do, but the loop needs to be done since I need to make sure that every employee id must be exist based on my filter before updating the said attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago I wrote an article about getting [better performance when programming with AD](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html). The short version is that you need to minimize the number of network requests and/or the amount of data being sent back and forth. There are a couple ways you can do that.

I see you're searching by `cn`. If all of the users are in the same OU, you could eliminate the search altogether and bind directly to each object. For example, if the users are all in the OU `OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com`, then you can do this:

```
foreach (string empId in employeeCN)
{
    try
    {
        using(var de = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{empId},OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com")) {
            de.Properties["a-excludelock"].Value = "Y";
            de.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: Log an error here why there's an error on the said appid
        continue;
    }
}
```

If the users are in different OUs, then you will have to search, but there are a couple things you can do. First, put *something* in [`directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload). If you don't, AD will return every attribute that has a value, which you don't need. It's just a waste of bandwidth. So just add any attribute so that only that attribute will be returned from the search.

```
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
```

You can also batch the searches, so it will search for, say, 50 at a time. I wrote an example in my article, but here it is adapted to your use case (I didn't actually run this, so you might find some bugs):

```
using (var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("my_ldap", "my_username", "my_password"))
{
    var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry) {
        PropertiesToLoad = { "cn" }
    };
    
    var filter = new StringBuilder();
    var numUsernames = 0;
    
    var e = employeeCN.GetEnumerator();
    var hasMore = e.MoveNext();
    
    while (hasMore) {
        var cn = e.Current;
        filter.Append($"(cn={cn})");
        numUsernames++;
        
        hasMore = e.MoveNext();
        if (numUsernames == 50 || !hasMore) {
            directorySearcher.Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(|{filter}))";
            
            using (var results = directorySearcher.FindAll()) {
                foreach (SearchResult searchResult in results) {
                    using (var de = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()) {
                        de.Properties["a-excludelock"].Value = "Y";
                        de.CommitChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            filter.Clear();
            numUsernames = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The other important thing is to wrap anything disposable in `using` blocks. Usually you don't need to worry about disposing `DirectoryEntry` objects since garbage collection cleans them up nicely. But when you're running a long loop, the garbage collector doesn't have time to run, so you'll find that your app will take up more and more memory as the loop goes on. If you're looking at 15k+ objects, that could easily take up a couple GB by the time it's done. All that memory allocation wastes time. So if you dispose of each object as you're done with it, it will save memory and time.

That said, you should *always* dispose a [`SearchResultCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection) (what `FindAll()` returns) - even when it's not run in a loop - because, as the documentation says:

> Due to implementation restrictions, the SearchResultCollection class cannot release all of its unmanaged resources when it is garbage collected. To prevent a memory leak, you must call the Dispose method when the SearchResultCollection object is no longer needed.